# How to obtain the confidence interval in cor.test?

Tags: r, correlation, confidence-interval

I have the following code:

```
corMy_PSQ_T <- cor.test(datET$My_scale, datET$PSQ, method="spearman", exact=FALSE)
```

My dataset is something like this:
[image]

But when I try to obtain the confidence interval it simply won't show up. I even got the structure and it is not included:

```
List of 8
 $ statistic  : Named num 29760
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "S"
 $ parameter  : NULL
 $ p.value    : num 0.186
 $ estimate   : Named num 0.173
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ null.value : Named num 0
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "rho"
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Spearman's rank correlation rho"
 $ data.name  : chr "datET$My_scale and datET$PSQ"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

I hope you can help me with it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I use `method="spearman"`, I don't get a confidence interval.  With `method="pearson"` it is the `conf.int` element of the result.

Comment: In the documentation it says: "conf.int" is currently only given for Pearson's product moment correlation.

Comment: As @pookpash already mentioned, you will not be able to calculate the CI for the spearman correlation with cor.test. Maybe try using another function, like SpearmanRho() from the package DescTools or spearman.ci() from RVAideMemories for CIs calculated with bootstrapping.

Comment: The name of the second package mentioned by @Maria-ChristinaWeber is [RVAideMemoire](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=RVAideMemoire)

Comment: Anyone know the rationale for not implementing spearman CIs in base cor.test?